# even spacing of html elements along timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline, spacing

I am trying to build a timeline that will scale, and add evenly spaced markers along side the 'timeline' so that the user can add additional times within an admin panel.

for instance, if there was 4 markers they would automatically split across 1/4 of the timeline regardless of width.

So like this <--|--|--|--|-->

Here is the code:

```
<style>

    body {
        background: black;
    }
#timeline {
    width:49.5%;
    background: url(http://brendonwells.co.uk/CPD/ice-training/img/timeline.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.checkpoint {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 13px;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkpoint:hover {
    background: white;
}

.checkpoint p {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width:0;
    bottom: -35px!important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
}

.checkpoint:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<div id="timeline">
                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <div class="rel">
                                <p>5 Minutes</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>10 Minutes</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>15 Minutes</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>20 Minutes</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>25 Minutes</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>30 Minutes</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="checkpoint" >
                            <p>35 Minutes</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>


        //Set slide times
        var time1 = 300;
        var time2 = 600;
        var time3 = 900;
        var time4 = 1200;
        var time5 = 1500;
        var time6 = 1800;
        var time7 = 2100;

        //Array to keep all the times
        var times = [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, time7];

        //variable to iterate through all of them
        var chosenTime = 0;

        //placement needs multiplier
        var multiplier = 1;

        function deliverTimes() {
            $('.checkpoint').each(function() {
                $(this).data("time", times[chosenTime]);
                //console.log("The data is " +  $(this).data('time'));
                chosenTime++;
                //console.log('running');
                placement($(this));
            });
        }

        //Call the function
        deliverTimes();

        //Clicking checkpoints
        $('.checkpoint').click(function() {
            video.currentTime = $(this).data("time");
        });

        //place the checkpoints

        function placement($div) {
            var width = $('#timeline').width();

            var margin = ((width/$('.checkpoint').length) - 10) * multiplier;
            console.log(margin);
            $div.css("left", margin + "px");
            multiplier++;
        }
                </script>
```

http://brendonwells.co.uk/timeline.html

I also prepared a link so that the CSS could be messed with etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired look utilizing CSS3 [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to handle the spacing and width. Add and remove checkpoints in the html and css will handle the rest. No JS required.

HTML

```
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="checkpoint">
        <div class="rel">
            <p>5 Minutes</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>10 Minutes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>15 Minutes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>20 Minutes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>25 Minutes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>30 Minutes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="checkpoint" >
        <p>35 Minutes</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

#timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
#timeline::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px dashed #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
#timeline .checkpoint {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
#timeline .checkpoint:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
#timeline .checkpoint p {
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
#timeline .checkpoint p:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s5rL5eja/

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thats exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this system here [Responsivegrid.css](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) to evenly space them, otherwise, you could use a function that sets the width for each of the checkpoints to a percentage of 100%. So if you have 5 checkpoints the width may be 19% per checkpoint/child, with a margin that is 1% of the total width, and then you would just give either the `checkpoint:first-child` or `checkpoint:last-child` a margin of 0% (I am not sure what class each of your checkpoints has but you just replace `checkpoint` with whatever class)

TLDR: Give each checkpoint a percentage of the entire width based on a js function. Make either the first or last checkpoint have a 0% margin.